# Kernel automatically restart after loading data when using AI platform of google cloud platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcp-ai-platform-notebook, gcp-ai-platform-training

I'm trying to load a 600 MB data using notebook of AI platform.

The data loading was fine at first, but right after the loading complete, the kernel will restart automatically. I've successfully load the data before, the issue comes after I do some preprocessing to the images while loading data.

I'm wondering if I have done anything wrong to make this happen since I'm new to GCP. I have tried to setup higher RAM but it still not work. And here is the code that trigger the problem.

```
for i in random.sample(items,5600):
  print(j)
  j += 1
  img = cv2.imread(PATH + "C1-P1_Train/" + labels[i][0])
  img = cv2.resize(img,size)
  img = cv2.resize(preprocess(img), size)
  X.append(img)
  y.append(labels[i][1])
print("Import successfully!")
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: does some message appear?

Comment: No, there's no message. The kernel just stop itself automatically.

Comment: What is the maximum value of 'j' it prints? Is it always the same? Did the value of j change when you set a higher RAM? Does it work locally?

Comment: Maximum of j is always 5600. I do it just for checking the image number read in is correct.

Comment: If you have 5600 items and maximum print is always 5600 it means it crahes in the last loop iteration or after the loop. Have you tried isolating what particular line is it? [I assume it never gets to print "import succesfully]